# CSS - Не работает выпадающий блок меню при наведении на ссылку <a>

Tags: html, css, вложенные-классы

Делаю выпадающий блок меню. Мне нужно, чтобы, наводя на слово-ссылку, выпадал блок. Если я в качестве селектора выбираю **div** с определённым классом, который окружает -ссылку, то это работает.
Но мне нужно, чтобы доп.блок появлялся только при наведении на само слово.
Пытаясь это сделать, я заменил **div** с классом на **a** с классом. Но выпадающий блок не появился.
Ниже кусочек кода меню, в котором при наведении на About появлялся блок с классом .sub (который изначально скрыт (display:none).

**Вот это работало:**

```css
.sub {
  display: none;
}

.button:hover .sub {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"><a href="" class="about">About</a>
  <div class="sub">
    <div><a href="">History</a></div>
    <div><a href="">Kitchen</a></div>
    <div><a href="">Our Price</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Это уже не работает:

```css
.sub {
  display: none;
}

.about:hover .sub {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="" class="about">About</a>
  <div class="sub">
    <div><a href="">History</a></div>
    <div><a href="">Kitchen</a></div>
    <div><a href="">Our Price</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Изначально я не хотел вообще задавать класс ссылке, а чтобы выглядело так.

```
.button a:hover .sub
```

Вопрос: что я не понял про работу ссылок и почему второй вариант не работает?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Перед тем как задать вопрос, я подумал о том, что .sub не вложен в .about. Я попробовал закрыть .about и после всего блока .sub, и после открывающего тега, но всё равно не работало. 
`<div class="button"><a href="" class="about">About<div class="sub"><div><a href="">History</a></div><div><a href="">Kitchen</a></div><div><a href="">Our Price</a></div></div>**</a>*</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потому что `class="sub"` не вложен в `class="about"`. Они находятся рядом, для этого нужно указать так:

```css
.sub {
  display: none;
}

.about:hover+.sub {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="" class="about">About</a>
  <div class="sub">
    <div><a href="">History</a></div>
    <div><a href="">Kitchen</a></div>
    <div><a href="">Our Price</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

или так, если хотите `.button a:hover .sub`

```css
.sub {
  display: none;
}

.button a:hover+.sub {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="" class="about">About</a>
  <div class="sub">
    <div><a href="">History</a></div>
    <div><a href="">Kitchen</a></div>
    <div><a href="">Our Price</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас при наведении на список, сам список исчезает, предлагаю такое решение: `.button a:hover + .sub, .button .sub:hover`

Comment: @ΝNL993 да, верно. Я понял вопрос был в том, что почему не работает стили в таком случае, а так да - проще будет навесить на класс `button"`